# Adding rows after groupby condition is met

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to find the number of consecutive negative values of 20 rows or more for a column in a dataframe. However, once it groups in chunks of 20 or more, I want to add corresponding 30 rows of the original dataframe after each chunk.

This is my attempt (got help from a posted question here):

```
n = df['Slope'].lt(0)
mask = n.ne(n.shift()).cumsum()[n]
dfL = [g for i, g  in df.groupby(mask) if (len(g[g['Slope'] < 0]) >= 20)]
df_cn = pd.concat(dfL)
```

I get the chunks of consecutive negative values, but I do not know how to now add corresponding 30 rows after each chunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to provide a minimal reproducible example next time and a small sample of the desired output

I created a random dfL of mine and it worked well

```
n = df['Slope'].lt(0)
mask = n.ne(n.shift()).cumsum()[n]
dfL = [g for i, g  in df.groupby(mask) if (len(g[g['Slope'] < 0]) >= 20)]
```

From here I created the code:

```
for x in range(len(dfL)): # dfL is reaturning a list of dfs with each chunk
  if len(dfL)>0: # here I want to be sure, that we have a chunk in the dfL
     df_cn= dfL[x] # selecting chunk from dfL
     print('Chunk: df_cn_' + str(x) + ' created') # feedback for testing
     idx=dfL[x].index # last index from chunk # since chunk size >=20, we need to be sure to get the last index of it.
     print('Chunk from ' + str(min(idx)) + ' to ' + str(max(idx)) + ' total ' + str(len(dfL[x]))+' indexes in the chunk') # feedback with size of chunk
     df_rest=df.loc[max(idx)+1:max(idx)+31] # get the next 30 rows from original df based on max index from last chunk
     df_cn_ext = pd.concat([df_cn, df_rest]) # concatenate (join on Y-Achse) the chunk and 30rows of original df, if the 
     exec(f'df_cn_ext_{x}=df_cn_ext[:]') # creating separated dataframes trough suffixes for each chunk + 30 rows groups
     print('Dataframe df_cn_ext_' + str(x) + ' created from index ' + str(min(idx)) + ' to ' + str(max(idx)+31))
  else:
    print('no chunks in the df found')
```

Please note:

1- I've separated each chunk+30 rows in new dfs with suffixes (df_cn_ext_suffix)

2- If the last value of chunk is near the end of dfL, it won't add 30 rows, but the maximum number of rows available.

here some output of my code:

```
Chunk: df_cn_0 created
Chunk from 3 to 39 total 37 indexes in the chunk
Dataframe df_cn_ext_0 created from index 3 to 70
Chunk: df_cn_1 created
Chunk from 41 to 66 total 26 indexes in the chunk
Dataframe df_cn_ext_1 created from index 41 to 97
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked wonderfully! I apologize in advance for not providing a reproducible df. I will definitely keep that in mind for the future!

Comment: @CVN you are very welcome. Pls kindly accept the answer above in order to recognize the author and close the question as well.